# Autocomplete in Jdeveloper 10.1.3

Tags: eclipse, jdeveloper

I am moving from Eclipse to JDev 10.1.3
I cannot do how to use auto-complete for classes that are not imported.
(In eclipse, the auto-completion where on the entire classes in the CLASSPATH)...

How to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to torture yourself from the nice Eclipse to the horrendous JDeveloper?

Comment: The work constraints man! we have to use Oracle AS (and OC4J)...

Answer (score 1):

The classpath in JDeveloper is defined in the project properties->libraries
Make sure to add your jars there if you want JDeveloper to find them and complete your code.